# JQuery Validate - Confirm email form validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a quiz, and i need to add some validation to a `confirm email address` field, basically it just has to match the email address given in the above field. I am using the following javascript, can i add something in here which will make sure the emails match?

```
if ($('#mtQuiz').length > 0) {
    $('#myQuiz').validate({
        errorElement: "em",
        errorContainer: $("#warning"),
        rules: {
            'entry[first_name]':            'required',
            'entry[last_name]':     'required',
            'entry[email]': {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            'entry[confirm_email]': {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            'entry[first_name]':    'Please enter first name',
            'entry[last_name]': 'Please enter last name',
            'entry[email]': {
                required: ' Please enter a valid email address',
                minlength: 'Not a valid email address'
            },
            'entry[confirm_email]': {
                required: ' Please make sure email matches above',
                minlength: 'Does not match above email address'
            }
                      }
    });
}
```

Comment: **There was no good reason for you to post a [second version of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22758997/email-validation-using-jquery-emails-matching) today.**  Please do not post duplicates... always edit/delete or follow-up with your first question.

Answer (score 9):

```
if ($('#mtQuiz').length > 0) { // <- unnecessary and superfluous
    $('#myQuiz').validate({
        // options, etc.
    });
}
```

You're using jQuery so you don't need to check for the existence of `#myQuiz` with `if ($('#mtQuiz').length > 0)`.  If the `#myQuiz` element doesn't exist, jQuery will simply ignore it without any errors.

This is all you need to do...

```
$('#myQuiz').validate({  // initialize the plugin
    // options, etc.
});
```

---

To match the value of another field, simply use [the `equalTo` rule](http://jqueryvalidation.org/equalTo-method/).  While using the `equalTo` rule, there is no need to duplicate any of the other rules since `equalTo` will always force the value to match the primary field's value which already followed its rules.

```
$('#myQuiz').validate({
    // options, etc.,
    rules: {
        'entry[first_name]': 'required',
        'entry[last_name]': 'required',
        'entry[email]': {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        'entry[confirm_email]': {
            //required: true,  // <- redundant, not needed with 'equalTo'
            //email: true      // <- redundant, not needed with 'equalTo'
            equalTo: '[name="entry[email]"]' // <- any valid jQuery selector
        }
    },
    // other options, etc.
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/JCY2E/**

Answer (score 4):

Have a look to [equalTo](http://jqueryvalidation.org/equalTo-method/) method.

```
$('#myQuiz').validate({
  ...
  rules: {
    ...
    'entry[confirm_email]': {
      equalTo: "entry[email]"
    }
  }
});
```