# Email Validation using JQuery (emails matching)

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the following validation on my form, as i have a `email address` field and `confirm email address` field i need some validation to make sure these two fields match, i currently have the following which is giving me the error message that it does not match even when it does, anyone know why this could be?

```
rules: {
            'entry[email]': {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            'entry[confirm_email]': {
            //  required: true,
                equalTo: "entry[email]"
            },
},
        messages: {
            'entry[email]': {
                required: ' Please enter a valid email address',
                minlength: 'Not a valid email address'
            },
            'entry[confirm_email]': {
                required: ' Please make sure email matches above',
                minlength: 'Does not match above email address'
            },
     }
```

Comment: even if my emails are matching correctly it is giving me the message that they do not

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle.

Comment: is "entry[email]" the id of the input element??

Comment: Sorry guys my bad i had a different id of the input element, works now! Thanks :)

Comment: **Why didn't you follow up with the [first version of your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22746091/jquery-validate-confirm-email-form-validation)?  NEVER post duplicates!**

Comment: You should have also included the HTML of the form in your OPs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way

```
rules:{
    pwd:{
         required:true //First email section
    },
    pwd1:{
        required:true,//Second email section
        equalTo: "#same" //Use id of the first email text box here
        }   
    },
 messages:{
    pwd1:{
        equalTo: "Must be same as above email"
     }
 }
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rF7LR/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#email).validate({
  ...
  rules: {
    ...
    'entry[confirm_email]': {
      equalTo: "entry[email]"
    }
  }
});
```

Here "entry[email]" should be the id of input element!!

Comment: _"Here `entry[email]` should be the `id` of input element!!"_  ~ **That is not true!!**  It only needs to be a valid jQuery selector.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/6ux42/